# Rspec controller test not passing validations, but has valid data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

I'm trying to write a controller test for my update route using Rspec with factory girl but I can't get my test to pass validations even though I'm pretty sure the data in my factories is valid.

Here are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username { Faker::Internet.user_name(8) }
    password 'password'
  end
  factory :post do
    title { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    body { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    author { Faker::Internet.user_name(8) }
  end
end
```

here is my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :body, :author, presence: true
end
```

Here is my test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe PostsController  do
    let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
    let!(:post) { FactoryGirl.create :post }
    let(:attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for :post }

describe 'PUT #update' do
  let(:title) { "A treatise on Malomars." }
  it 'updates a field on a blog post' do
      put :update, id: post.id, post: {title: title}
      expect(post.reload.title).to eq(post.title)
    end
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
 Failure/Error: put :update, id: post.id, post: {title: title}
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Body can't be blank
```

EDIT---
here is the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    post = Post.new
    post.title = params[:title]
    post.body = params[:body]
    post.author = "#{session[:username].titleize} Force"
    redirect_to root_path
    post.save!
  end

  def show
    p session[:id]
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.title = params[:post][:title]
    post.body = params[:post][:body]
    post.save!
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: And where is the controller?

Comment: controller is in app/controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strong parameters aside, you're setting `post.body` to `nil` since you're not passing a value for the `body` parameter in your test. When you call `save!` in your controller, you're getting an error because you have a validation for `body` being present (i.e. not `nil`).

Comment: changed it to       `put :update, id: post.id, post: {title: title, body: post.body}` it's passing, now. I think I figured that the body would already be there as it's already present in the factory, but looking at it now I see that it has to be passed in just the same. Thanks for your help.